# Send parameter on Button Click . (ASP . net C#)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an asp button, and I want to send parameter to codebehind when it's click.
so I do like this tutorial:
http://www.devchix.com/2007/08/10/aspnet-passing-parameters-in-button-click-handler/

I have button:

```
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" CommandArgument="MyVal1"
   CommandName="ThisBtnClick" OnClick="MyBtnHandler" />
```

and event :

```
  void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            switch (btn.CommandName)
            {
                case "ThisBtnClick":
                   //lala
                    break;
            }
```

but when I run , there is a ' Compilation Error'.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.softwares_aspx' does not contain
>   a definition for 'MyBtnHandler' and no extension method 'MyBtnHandler'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.softwares_aspx' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 110:            Line 111:             Line 112:
>    Line 114:

why?

thanks!!

Comment: You need to make it either `public` or `protected` for it to be used as part of the `OnClick` handler.  Functions, as standard, are `private` if they are not specifically stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment - if you don't give permission to a function it becomes `private` as standard.

If you give it either `public` or `protected`, then the function can be seen by the `OnClick` handler.

For preference, I would go with `protected`, meaning the click handler will see it, but it won't become an available function to other classes.  (Unless they're derived, which is a whole other subject)

So change...

```
void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

To...

```
protected void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: thanks. I have another little problem..I try to transfer as parameter a value from C# object called s:
CommandArgument="<%=s.SoftwareID%>"
but it's transfer that like a String of : <%=s.SoftwareID%>
instead of send the id. why?

Comment: This is a common mistake.  Any server-side control (basically anything with `runat="server"` cannot have code blocks within attributes (the major exception to this is when you use `<%# %>` in repeaters).  What you need to do is set the attribute in the code-behind

Comment: I understand..it's problem for me to do that on code behind.
there is option to send a paramter with html button and OnServerClick
?

Comment: No, I don't think so @user, because in order for you to use `OnServerClick` you have to have `runat="server"` which then turns it into a server-side control

Comment: If my answer has answered your original question @user, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.  This will tell the community that your problem is solved, and helps future readers who find your question